# how to implement Algolia on Android with Kotlin to query Firestore with multiple queries?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

I have seen a video of @AlexMamo on it but to be honest I have no clue on how to work around it considering it is in Java.
Algolia docs on Android intergration is not clear to me especially the **kotlin client Api**

I want the user to be able to query using either location, rent or rooms]
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChPeT.png)

Any relevant docs or examples will be appreciated.

Comment: Hey Sam. Have you tried implementing [Algolia Extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/algolia-firestore-algolia-search)?

Comment: @AlexMamo I did not know it existed but let me implement it.

Comment: Ok. Give it a try and tell me if it works.